# What is causing the error "cannot convert value of type 'CLLocation.Type' to expected argument type 'CLLocation'"

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocation, reverse-geocoding

I am attempting to add location detection to an app and for the most part I have it figured out. But I am having issues with the `reverseGeocodeLocation` method. I am getting the error `cannot convert value of type 'CLLocation.Type' to expected argument type 'CLLocation'`. What would be causing this? Here is my code:

```
func loadLocation() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 2000
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    var location = locations.first
    var geoCoder: CLGeocoder!

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location: CLLocation) { (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                                    ^ Error Here
        var placemark: CLPlacemark = placemarks?.first
        self.location = placemark.locality
        self.location = placemark.administrativeArea
    }
}
```

`locationManager` and `location` are called above the `viewDidLoad`:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var location: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadLocation()
    retrieveWeatherForecast()
}
```

If you find any other issues with my code you can point that out also.

### Update:

After making the changes that trojanfoe suggested, this is what I have:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let location = locations.first
    var geoCoder: CLGeocoder!

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location!) { (placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let placemark: CLPlacemark = (placemarks?.first)!
        self.location = placemark.locality
        self.location = placemark.administrativeArea
    }
}
```

Xcode wants me to change `var geoCoder: CLGeocoder!` to `let geoCoder: CLGeocoder!`. If I do, I get this error `Variable 'geoCoder' captured by a closure before being initialized`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLLocation` is the class (i.e. the *type*).

Don't you want to pass it one of the instances within the array that is passed to that method?

For example:

```
var location = locations.first
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location: location) { ...
```

Comment: @CalebKleveter Yeah you will need to initialize `geoCoder` before using it.

Comment: How is that done in Swift? I know how to do it in Objective-C, but not Swift.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Updated answer.